# What to do when $a(x_{n}, x_{n+1}^{\prime}) = 0$ in Metropolis-Hasting algorithm

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

**My question**.
I think the lecture notes I read is not very clear in this step : In the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm, what to do when $a(x_{n}, x_{n+1}^{\prime}) = 0$ ? we generate again $U_{n+1}^{\prime}$ until we get $x_{n+1}^{\prime}$ such that $a(x_{n}, x_{n+1}^{\prime}) > 0$ ? Moreover, it's said we need to, in practice, choose the control matrix $A$ such that $\forall i \in E, \mathrm{Card}\{j \in E \mid a(i, j) > 0\}$ not too big, which I guess is for the construction of $\Phi_{A}$ on computer.

Here is the context from the lecture notes :

**Metropolis-Hasting matrix**.  Let $E$ be a finite set, $\pi$ a probability measure on $E$ such that $\pi(x) > 0$ for all $x \in E$. Let $A = (a(i, j))_{i, j \in E}$ be a control matrix on $E$ (i.e. $A$ is a irreducible transition matrix on $E$ such that $\forall i, j \in E, a(i, j) > 0 \iff a(j, i) > 0$). Let $h : ]0, +\infty[ \rightarrow ]0, 1]$ such that for all $u \in ]0, +\infty[$, $uh(1/u) = h(u)$. Then $Q := (p(i, j))_{i, j \in E}$ defined by :

$$\forall i, j \in E, \quad p(i, j)= \begin{cases}0 & \text { if } i \neq j \text { and } a(i, j)=0 \\ a(i, j) h\left(\frac{\pi(j) a(j, i)}{\pi(i) a(i, j)}\right) & \text { if } i \neq j \text { and if } a(i, j)>0 \\ 1-\sum_{k \in E \backslash\{i\}} p(i, k) & \text { if } i=j .\end{cases}$$

is a irreducible transition matrix reversible with stationnary distribution $\pi$. Moreover, if $h(u) < 1$ for all $u \in ]0, +\infty[$, then $Q$ is aperiodic.

**Metropolis-Hasting algorithm**.
Suppose a software provide a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and two sequences $(U_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(U_{n}^{\prime})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of independant random variables of uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$. Suppose we have contructed $\Phi_{A} : E \times [0, 1] \rightarrow E$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Phi_{A}(i, U) = j) = a(i, j)$ for all $i, j \in E$ and random variable $U$ of uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$

- $n = 0$ : we choose $x_{0} \in E$ randomly.
- $n \rightarrow n+1$ : let $x_{n+1}^{\prime} = \Phi_{A}(x_{n}, U_{n+1}^{\prime})$. If $U_{n+1} < h(\frac{\pi(x_{n+1}^{\prime}) a(x^{\prime}_{n+1}, x_{n})}{\pi(x_{n}) a(x_{n}, x_{n+1}^{\prime})})$, we let $x_{n+1} = x_{n+1}^{\prime}$. Else, we let $x_{n+1} = x_{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $a(x_n,x'_{n+1})=a(x_n,\Phi_A(x_n,U))>0$ almost surely i.e. with probability $1$. Although the mathematical theory can only really guarantee that much, in practice you can set this up to be sure, not just almost sure, since you get to define $\Phi_A$ yourself.

Or, in other words: what $\Phi_A(i,U)$ does is achieve a time step of your proposal chain, so you will always get something that you had a positive probability to get out of the proposal chain.